# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database get single data query result value null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/live-chat-831e0.appspot.com/o/Ek%20A%C3%A7%C4%B1klama%202020-01-31%20231341.png?alt=media&token=096b97a0-e4df-4e18-b393-a154e8ec32b4))</sub>

Path = userTokens

uid = W9aafYsF6cOPr1sMLKlnFEUcNNR2

```
userTokens/W9aafYsF6cOPr1sMLKlnFEUcNNR2
```

I want to bring the underlined area in the picture. How should I write a query with Firebase Realtime Database?

***The result variable is null.***

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class NotificationServiceTools {
  static final FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = new FirebaseDatabase();

  static Future<String> getUserTokens({@required String uid}) async {
    final String result =
        (await firebaseDatabase.reference().child("userTokens/$uid").once())
            .value
            .toString();
    print("result: $result");

    return result;
  }
}
```

where the function is called :

```
print(receiver);
token = await NotificationServiceTools.getUserTokens(uid: receiver);
print("token : " + token);
```

log :

```
I/flutter ( 9447): vUpgi1QyU1UxK7tCJ5rcJqnOdaO2
I/flutter ( 9447): result : null
I/flutter ( 9447): token : null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
String result;
await firebaseDatabase.instance
.reference()
.child('userTokens/$uid')
.once()
.then((snapshot){result=snapshot.value;});
```

Comment: snapshot.value returned null

Comment: @TheNobleBrain what is the name of the root? is it `'userTokens/$uid'` for sure?

Comment: @TheNobleBrain and are you giving the correct `uid` as an input to `getUserTokens()`?

Comment: @TheNobleBrain so your root node is 'userTokens/vUpgi1QyU1UxK7tCJ5rcJqnOdaO2'? you've hidden that part in the screenshot and it's important

Comment: @TheNobleBrain why is 'vUpgi1QyU1UxK7tCJ5rcJqnOdaO2' being passed to `getUserTokens()`? and you still haven't cleared up the root, what is above `userTokens` in the screenshot?

Comment: Since the database does not have the necessary data, it returns null. Excuse me. I made a plus as a compensation.

Comment: @TheNobleBrain Yeah I was wondering why that particular `uid` was being passed even though it's not available in your database, glad you figured it out :D